# tnsping result with more than 0 ms. what is solution?

Tags: oracle, networking

i ping my oracle database via tnsping. its local database. this is not in local network. I expected 0 ms, but it is giving more than 0 ms. this is tns ping result for 20 times;

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sdemirkeser>tnsping belsoft 20

TNS Ping Utility for 32-bit Windows: Version 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on 17-MAY-2
012 09:23:32

Copyright (c) 1997, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 Used parameter files:
 C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora

 Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
 Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)
 (HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = BELSOFT)))
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (20 msec)
```

what do you think about why it could be more than 0 ms. or is it normal?

i ping with normal ping command but it is faster than 1 ms

```
C:\Documents and Settings\sdemirkeser>ping localhost

32 bayt veri ile sdemirkeser [127.0.0.1] 'ping' ediliyor:

127.0.0.1 cevabı: bayt=32 süre<1ms TTL=128
127.0.0.1 cevabı: bayt=32 süre<1ms TTL=128
127.0.0.1 cevabı: bayt=32 süre<1ms TTL=128
127.0.0.1 cevabı: bayt=32 süre<1ms TTL=128

127.0.0.1 için Ping istatistiği:
    Paket: Giden = 4, Gelen = 4, Kaybolan = 0 (0% kayıp),
Mili saniye türünden yaklaşık tur süreleri:
    En Az = 0ms, En Çok = 0ms, Ortalama = 0ms
```

If it is not normal what will i do

Thank for everyone who interested in
Sincerly Yours
Suleyman Demirkeser

Comment: Try ping localhost. Due to the tcp/ip Stack there's always a minimum of latency. In other words: It's normal.

Comment: 20 millisecond delay times on a local database seem rather long to me.  I agree with @int2000, though - try `ping localhost`, see what you get, and report back (edit your post and add the ping results).

Answer (score 1):

If you're logged into database server, use IPC connection rather than TCP.

Answer (score 0):

If if ain't no broken, do not fix it. Is >0ms ping time a problem? I do not think so. Oracle might have other things to do (say, writing redo log or some other admin task; I do not think it's ever truly idle).
As long as it does not impact your work, do not worry about this minuscule response time. Since you are using a 32 bit Windows, it is most likely not a production environment, anyhow.
My local TNSPing times vary between 10ms and 40ms, while the pinging localhost shows an average 0ms response time.